# Why doesn't it prevent further looping?

Tags: php

My code does not seem to stop after 6 and 2 iterations - why is this? I do not want more than 6 values displayed from services, and 2 values from cultures.

```
ECHO "<fieldset>Services: ";
$servicearray = mysql_query("select serv_id from org_serv_xref where org_id='".$org_id."'");
while ($servicearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servicearray)) {
    $servdescarray = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$servicearrayrow['serv_id']."'");
    $i = 0;
    while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
        if ($i < 6) {
            ECHO $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc']." ";
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
ECHO "</fieldset>";
ECHO "<fieldset>Cultures: ";
$culturearray = mysql_query("select cult_id from org_cult_xref where org_id='".$org_id."'");
while ($culturearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($culturearray)) {
    $cultdescarray = mysql_query("select cult_desc from culture where cult_id='".$culturearrayrow['cult_id']."'");
    $i = 0;
    while ($cultdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($cultdescarray)) {
        if ($i < 2) {
            ECHO $cultdescarrayrow['cult_desc']." ";
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
ECHO "</fieldset>";
```

Comment: Because when you `break;` the second while loop you keep running the outer `while` loop in wich the `$i` gets reset to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `break 2` instead of `break`, `break 2` exit 2 level of loop.

Have a look at the [doc](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).

You could also use `LIMIT 6` in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are **REDECLARING** the same variable over and over inside and outside the loop which messes things up:

```
while ($servicearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servicearray)) {
    $servdescarray = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$servicearrayrow['serv_id']."'");

    $i = 0;
    while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) { //<<WHA??
```

Comment: How would I go about not doing that?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander why do you need the additional loop at all? Just remove it. You're just executing the same sql over and over.

Comment: $servicearray selects from a xref table. $servicearrayrow is used to execute a SQL statement which pulls multiple serv_id's from the xref table table. $servdescarray then uses those serv_id's to pull serv_descs from the service table. I then iterate through $servdescarray and echo the values with $servdescarrayrow.